# What is the pressure at the center of the Earth? (Or a neutron star)

Tags: gravity, pressure, neutron-stars

The [center of the Earth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_core) has microgravity and is thought to be solid and almost 6000 degrees hot. What is the pressure like there? The confusing thing, for the common man I suppose, is that there's no gravity there, but lots of matter around it which does gravitate towards the center. How does that add up? Is the center just a gas cloud or is it highly compressed?

And I could add the aside question about what it is like in the microgravity center of a [neutron star](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_star) or a black hole, but I don't expect anyone to know about that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The pressure at any point is the total weight of everything above an area of a square metre. So for example the atmospheric pressure at Earth's surface, 101325 Pa, means the total weight of atmosphere above a square metre at the surface is 101325 N.

So when you ask for the pressure at the centre of the Earth, the way to calculate this is to work out the total weight of all the iron and rock above a square metre. The problem is that the weight is equal to the mass multiplied by the acceleration due to gravity, and as you say in the question the acceleration due to gravity changes as we go down from the surface to the centre.

Doing the calculation requires a knowledge of the density change with depth, and actually doing the calculation is somewhat involved so i'm going to chicken out and just show you the results. The pressure depth curve looks like:

[image: Pressure-depth curve]

([image from this web site](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/EarthSci/people/lidunka/GEOL2014/Geophysics7%20-%20Deep%20Earth/Earth%20Structure.htm))

So the answer to your question is that the pressure at the centre of the Earth is about 365 GPa. For comparison, this is about 3.6 million atmospheres.

The centre is very highly compressed. The gravity may be zero at the centre, but it still has all the matter above it pressing down. The core is solid iron-nickel with a density of about 13000 kg per cubic metre. For comparison, the density at the surface of iron is about 8000 kg/m$^3$ and nickel is 9000 kg/m$^3$, so you can se how compressed the core is.

Comment: Does the microgravity near the center play any significant role for the pressure there?

Comment: No, the pressure is dominated by the matter far from the centre where the gravity is not zero.

Comment: How does matter press down at a point where there is no down?

Comment: Down is towards that point for everywhere except that point. If you consider micro-gravity region right around the core, the pressure will be about equal on all sides, compressing everything. This is nothing new: the pressure in a fluid like air or water is also about the same in all directions, but for a somewhat different reason. (The downward weight makes everything want to expand sideways to let the stuff above get lower.)

Comment: *sideways or up

Comment: This might help: Imagine that the core of the Earth somehow magically was teleported out and replaced with air. The region replaced with air would have some shape and would contain the Earth's center of mass. Anywhere along the walls of the region, even though local gravity would be negligible, if you went far enough in that direction you would find lots and and lots of mass being pulled toward you by gravity. Thus, the wall near you will be pushed in by this weight. Since this is true for all the walls, the cavity will collapse until the air pressure matches the weight pressure.

Comment: I think that if you did this with a region a mile away from the exact core of the Earth almost exactly the same thing would happen. Even the wall pointing towards the core would exert pressure upwards into the cavity because the weight of that one mile of metal falling towards the core from your side in microgravity is nothing compared to entire height of the Earth on the other side of the core from you pressing down with real gravity.

Comment: I just realized that I put "you" inside of the cavity of air in that last comment. Sorry about that:)